# "DLLNotFoundException"?

Tags: c#, c++, native, native-code

I'm trying to import a native DLL made in C++ to C#. I'm having a little problem.

Here is my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("hello2dll.dll")] //I didn't know what to name it :'(
        private static extern void SayHi();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.ReadKey();
                SayHi();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is main.h from the DLL:

```
#ifndef __MAIN_H__
#define __MAIN_H__

#include <windows.h>

/*  To use this exported function of dll, include this header
 *  in your project.
 */

#ifdef BUILD_DLL
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
    #endif

     void DLL_EXPORT SayHi();

    #ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // __MAIN_H__
```

And then here is main.cpp from the DLL:

```
#include "main.h"

#include<windows.h>

void SayHi()
{
    MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP, "Hello!", "Hello!", 0);
}
```

So I tried to access the DLL by putting it in system32 then I tried to add it in the project by copying and pasting it into visual c# but so far I has no success. I'm kinda disappointed that it didn't work but who knows.

Comment: What error do you get?  Or do you just get no message box?

Comment: 1. 32 or 64 bit windows?  Many problems are caused by the lack of a platform suitable .dll.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why its failing rather I would create a CLR compatible assembly

You can create a CLR compatible assembly using [tblimp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then you can add reference to the assembly rather than importing it.